# The action 'update' could not be found for MessagesController

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to add the compose box on the message view so that it can send a new message that references the original message id. The code I have is giving me a `The action 'update' could not be found for MessagesController`. It should not be updating the current record, as it's supposed to be submitting a new message id and referencing the `original_message_id`.

Should I change how the form submits itself? As on my working reply page the page url is `http://localhost:3000/users/1/messages/new?reply_to=3` and that submits a new message. With my current code I am being directed to `http://localhost:3000/users/1/messages/new`

Can someone take a look and let me know what I am doing wrong?

Message show with compose box:

```
        <strong>From:</strong> 
        <%= @message.sender %>
    </p>

    <p>
        <strong>Received:</strong> 
        <%= @message.created_at.strftime('%B %-d, %Y %l:%M%P') %>
    </p>
    <p>

        <strong>Subject:</strong> 
        <%= @message.subject %>
    </p>

    <p>
        <strong>Message</strong><br />
        <%=h @message.body %>
    </p>

<%= form_for @message, :url => new_user_message_path(@user, :reply_to => @message.sender.id) do |f| %>
      <% if @message.recipient_id.nil? %>
        <p>
          To:<br />
           <%= f.hidden_field :recipient_id, :value => params[:user_id] %> 
        </p>

      <% end %>
          <p>
            <%= f.hidden_field :subject %>
          </p>
          <p>
            Reply:<br />
            <%= f.text_area :body %>
          </p>

          <%= submit_tag "Send"%>
    <% end %>

    <p>
        <% if @message.next %>
          <%= link_to 'Next', user_message_path(current_user, @message.next) %>
        <% end %>
        <% if @message.previous %>
          <%= link_to 'Previous', user_message_path(current_user, @message.previous) %>
        <% end %>
        </p>

    <p>
        <% if @message.recipient == @user %>

        <%= link_to "Reply", new_user_message_path(@user, :reply_to => @message.sender.id) %>

         |
        <% end %>
        <%= link_to "Inbox", user_messages_path(current_user, :mailbox=>:inbox)%>
        |
        <%= link_to "Delete", [current_user, @message], :confirm => 'Are you sure you want to delete this message?', :method => :delete %>

    </p>
```

Messages controller:

```
  before_filter :set_user

  def index
    if params[:mailbox] == "sent"
      @messages = @user.sent_messages.paginate :per_page => 10, :page => params[:page], :order => "created_at DESC"
    elsif params[:mailbox] == "inbox"
      @messages = @user.received_messages.paginate :per_page => 10, :page => params[:page], :order => "created_at DESC"
    #elsif params[:mailbox] == "archived"
     # @messages = @user.archived_messages
    end
    if params[:mailbox] == "unread"
    @messages = @user.unread_messages.paginate :per_page => 10, :page => params[:page], :order => "created_at DESC"
  end
  if params[:mailbox] == "trash"
    @messages = @user.deleted_messages.paginate :per_page => 10, :page => params[:page], :order => "created_at DESC"
  end
  end

  def new
    @message = Message.new
    if params[:reply_to]
      @reply_to = User.find_by_id(params[:reply_to])
      unless @reply_to.nil?
        @message.recipient_id = @reply_to.id
      end
    end
  end

  def create
    @message = Message.new(params[:message])
    @message.sender_id = @user.id
    if @message.save
      flash[:notice] = "Message has been sent"
      redirect_to user_messages_path(current_user, :mailbox=>:inbox)
    else
      render :action => :new
    end
  end

  def show
      @message = Message.find(params[:id])
      @message.readingmessage if @message.recipient == current_user
    end


   def destroy
     @message = Message.find(params[:id])
     @message.destroy
     flash[:notice] = "Successfully deleted message."
     redirect_to user_messages_path(@user, @messages)
   end

  def delete_multiple
      if params[:delete]
        params[:delete].each { |id|
          @message = Message.find(id)
          @message.mark_message_deleted(@message.id,@user.id) unless @message.nil?
        }
        flash[:notice] = "Messages deleted"
      end
      redirect_to user_messages_path(@user, @messages)
  end

  def reply
    @message = Message.find(params[:id]).reply(id)
  end

  private
    def set_user
      @user = current_user
  end
end
```

Messages model:

```
    attr_accessible :subject, :body, :sender_id, :recipient_id, :read_at,:sender_deleted,:recipient_deleted
    validates_presence_of :subject, :message => "Please enter message title"
    has_many :notifications, as: :event
    belongs_to :user
  scope :unread, -> {where('read_at IS NULL')}
  scope :not_deleted_by_recipient, where('messages.recipient_deleted IS NULL OR messages.recipient_deleted = ?', false)
  scope :not_deleted_by_sender, where('messages.sender_deleted IS NULL OR messages.sender_deleted = ?', false)

    belongs_to :sender,
    :class_name => 'User',
    :foreign_key => 'sender_id'
    belongs_to :recipient,
    :class_name => 'User',
    :foreign_key => 'recipient_id'


    def reply
      new_message.reply_from_user_id = self.id #save the user id of original repost, to keep track of where it originally came from
  end

  def self.by_date
      order("created_at DESC")
    end

    # marks a message as deleted by either the sender or the recipient, which ever the user that was passed is.
    # When both sender and recipient marks it deleted, it is destroyed.
    def mark_message_deleted(id,user_id)
            self.sender_deleted = true if self.sender_id == user_id
            self.recipient_deleted = user_id if self.recipient_id == user_id
            (self.sender_deleted > 0 && self.recipient_deleted > 0) ? self.destroy : self.save!
            (self.sender_deleted != 0 && self.recipient_deleted != 0)
        end
    # Read message and if it is read by recipient then mark it is read
    def readingmessage
      self.read_at ||= Time.now
      save
    end

    # Based on if a message has been read by it's recipient returns true or false.
    def read?
        self.read_at.nil? ? false : true
    end

    def self.received_by(user)
       where(:recipient_id => user.id)
     end

     def self.not_recipient_deleted
       where("recipient_deleted = ?", false)
     end

     def self.sent_by(user)
        Message.where(:sender_id => user.id)
      end

      def next(same_recipient = true)
        collection = Message.where('id <> ? AND created_at > ?', self.id, self.created_at).order('created_at ASC')
        collection.where(recipient_id: self.recipient_id) if same_recipient
        collection.first
      end

      def previous(same_recipient = true)
        collection = Message.where('id <> ? AND created_at < ?', self.id, self.created_at).order('created_at DESC')
        collection.where(recipient_id: self.recipient_id) if same_recipient
        collection.first
      end
    end

    private
    def send_notification(message)
      message.notifications.create(user: message.recipient)
    end
```

Comment: Am I missing something or is there really no "update" method defined in your script?

Comment: Sorry I just noticed that after I submitted. I did add the update just now, but there shouldn't be a update method. I am not updating a message, I am submitting a new record.

Answer (score 0):

You are really missing the update method in your Controller. Implementing it should solve your problem.